# JavaFX stop() method freezing GUI

Tags: user-interface, javafx, methods, freeze

I have an application that uses the stop() method to do cleanup tasks (close threads, free up resources, etc).  That cleanup is all encapsulated into one Task object and that task's progress is bound to ProgressBar and Label components, like so (note that the headless value is obtained from reading a config file and just means that the user has chose to run the app with no GUI, in this case it's obviously set to false) :

```
CompleteShutdownTask task = new CompleteShutdownTask();

    if (!headless)
    {
        ProgressBar progressBar = statusBar.getProgressBar();
        progressBar.progressProperty().unbind();
        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        Label progressLabel = statusBar.getProgressLabel();
        progressLabel.textProperty().unbind();
        progressLabel.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    }
```

I know this logic works because I also have an initialization task bound to these components in the exact same way when the program starts and that works fine.  My issue is that the task runs fine but the GUI becomes completely unresponsive while the stop() method runs.  I even have a super simple method to disable the buttons while this runs and even that doesn't work, the GUI is completely frozen while stop() executes.

Is it normal for this sort of GUI freezing to occur while the stop() method executes?

Comment: According to the javadoc you shouldn't access JavaFX after the `stop` method returns. Furthermore the `stop` method runs on the javafx application thread which means unless you enter a nested event loop, there's no point in modifying the GUI in the `stop` method. There's no indication of you entering a nested event loop in your code snippet which means you're either trying to use JavaFX after the `stop` method returns, or you're running a long-running operation blocking the application thread...

Comment: I see, thanks for that info.  How would one perform clean-up code that also needs to update the GUI as the application is closed (both by my own shutdown button and the X button of the window)?

Comment: The `onCloseRequest` event handler of a `Window` allows you to listen to the X "button" and even prevent it from closing the window. If you still need to display content while shutting down, It would probably best to not really shut down the app, until everything that you wanted to display was displayed and then use `Platform.exit` to really shut down the app...